# bpf_trace_printk format pointer

Tags: c, bpf, ebpf

How is `"%p"` implemented in `bpf_trace_printk`? It seems very different with `printf`.

```c
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>

int print_args(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    void *ptr = (void*)PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx);
    bpf_trace_printk("args: %lx %p %ld\n", ptr, ptr, ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I use this eBPF program to trace argument to one function. The parameter's type is a pointer to some struct.

One output is:
`args:  7ffde047d6c4     00000000ec7e9023    140728366257860`

We can notice that the output of `"%p"` is very strange.
If we use a standard C program to check the output:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    void *ptr = (void*)0x7ffde047d6c4;
    printf("args: %lx %p %ld\n", ptr, ptr, ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

We will get: `args:  7ffde047d6c4     0x7ffde047d6c4     140728366257860`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR.** The value you're seeing is a hash of the actual address, computed by [`ptr_to_id()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.8/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L790). The address is hashed to avoid pointer leaks while still being able to use this value as a unique identifier.

---

**Explanations.** The implementation of the `bpf_trace_printk` helper can be found in [`kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.8/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L330) in the kernel sources. Most of the code is there to restrict what specifiers you can use, before calling [`__trace_printk()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.8/source/kernel/trace/trace_printk.c#L230). You can follow the trail of functions to [`vsnprintf()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.8/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2504) which, for `%p`, calls [`pointer()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.8/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2179) whose [default behavior is to hash the address to avoid pointer leaks](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.8/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2175).